# Prevent TextField with an action to submit its form

Tags: ember.js

I have a `{{view Ember.TextField action="foo"}}` nested in a `<form>` tag:

```
My form:
<form>
  {{view Ember.TextField action="foo"}}
</form>
```

I hoped pressing `enter` in this textfield will call the action `foo`, without triggering a `submit` event on its form (because, by default, `Ember.TextField#bubbles` is set to `false`).  But it is not the case: the page is reloaded.

For semantic and integration purpose, I would like to keep the `<form>` tag, and do not write an `Ember.Form` view.

[You can test it in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lcoq/Ap7AV/).

How could I achieve this ?

PS: I'm using ember-latest:

- version: v1.0.0-pre.4-31-g16442c5
- last commit: 16442c5 (2013-01-23 23:48:09 -0800)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<form {{ action "" on="submit" }}>` will prevent the form submission.  (This is basically equivalent to the `onsubmit="return false;"` suggestion in another answer.)

Comment: When I wrote this question I was looking for a better solution than manually specify the `return false;` in the template.

Comment: I finally ended with a helper which generates a <form> tag which disable the submit event. It appears less "hackish" to me than specifying a blank action on submit. Did you see that case in the documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpliest way is to add onsubmit="return false;" on the form element. Or with jQuery , preventDefault();

I'm sure this is not the **best** way but it work!